# make POST request to db.json with multiple attributes inside object

Tags: javascript, ajax, json-server

I have the following code:

```
function createObject(){
  let object = {
    product1 : "Apple",
    product2 : "Banana",
    product3 : "Cucumber",
    product4 : "Duba",
    product5 : "Emil",
    product6 : "Fidschi",
  }

  return object
}

function commonAJAXPOSTCall(jsonstring){
  return $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: jsonstring,
    url: "http://localhost:3000/posts"
  }).then((response) => {
    return response
  })
}

export async function jsonDBSetter(){
    let object = createObject()
    //console.log(object)
    object = JSON.stringify(object)
    let resultCheck = await commonAJAXPOSTCall(object)
    console.log(resultCheck)

}
```

Now the problem is that ultimately, the data from the object is not inserted into "posts" table as I want to. 
I want every property to be inserted into its own row, so that I have "key => value", just as it is inside the object. 
However, the actual behavior is that the JSON server creates one key and then saves the whole JSON string to this singular key.

Im very new to using json server and so far I didnt really find anything useful explaining exactly what to do for my usecase...

EDIT: And I would like to avoid a "workaround" where I loop through the object and make an AJAX call for every single member of the JS object.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
return $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: jsonstring,
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: "http://localhost:3000/posts"
}).then((response) => {
    return response
})
```

If it's nor working, you can try to use a Formdata instead like this :

```
function createObject(){
    let form_data = new FormData();

    form_data.append('product1', "Apple");
    form_data.append('product2', "Banana");
    form_data.append('product3', "Cucumber");
    form_data.append('product4', "Duba");
    form_data.append('product5', "Emil");
    form_data.append('product6', "Fidschi");

    return form_data;
}

function commonAJAXPOSTCall(formdata){
  return $.ajax({
    dataType: 'text',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: formdata,
    url: "http://localhost:3000/posts"
  }).then((response) => {
    return response
  })
}

export async function jsonDBSetter(){
    let formdata = createObject()
    let resultCheck = await commonAJAXPOSTCall(formdata)
    console.log(resultCheck)

}
```

Comment: Thanks!
For some reason, when using your formdata approach, no data at all is appearing on my JSON server ^^ 
A new row with an id is created, but it doesnt contain any data. 

The first approach youve mentioned still just throws everything into one row, instead of creating individual rows for each key => value pair.

Comment: @baryon123 For the first approach, in your JSON server, you're supposed to decode the received row so it can become a dictionary (key => value pair)!